# Trying to center child element both vertically and horizontally with CSS

Tags: html, css, centering

How would I be able to vertically and horizontally a child element in terms of the parent.

```
#bigBanner  {
position: relative;
width: 960px;
height: 483px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-image:url(../wpimages/sliderbg.jpg);
}

#bannerQuote    {
width: 518px;
height: 127px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #0d0f11;
opacity: 0.95;
filter:Alpha(opacity=95);
}
```

Is the code, with bannerQuote being exactly in the middle of bigBanner. How would I achieve this? I have a feeling it's something quite simple.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like...

```
#bannerQuote {
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -259px;
  margin-top: -64px;
  width: 518px;
  height: 127px;
  background-color: #0d0f11;
  opacity: .95;
  filter:Alpha(opacity=95);
}
```

where the margin-left and margin-top are determined by your height and width. Since you are setting the top-left corner to the center of the parent's container, you'd want to bring the child element half of its width back to the left and half of its height back toward the top.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you have a child with specific height and width in a parent element with specifc height and width you could just position the child absolute from top and left.
Like:

```
#bannerQuote    {
 position:absolute;
 top: 178px;
 left: 221px;
 width: 518px;
 height: 127px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: #0d0f11;
 opacity: 0.95;
 filter:Alpha(opacity=95);
}
```

If you want to position a child with known height and width in a parent with dynamic values see fletchs answer.